# Radio button not clicked while using ko in Magento 2, anybody have idea?

Tags: magento-2.1, knockoutjs

when using like below standard in knockout js radio button click,

```
data-bind="click: submitValue.bind($data,'5','129.00')">
```

the radio button option not clicked (though I have used `return true` in the submitValue function), but if I use like this,

```
data-bind="click: submitValue('5','129.00')">
```

It works.

Do we have any specific reason on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue solved by using the following,

```
data-bind="checked:setMyRadio, data-bind="click: submitValue.bind($data,'5','129.00')"
```

Then in the knockout js file,

```
this.setMyRadio = ko.observable('1');

    submitValue: function (id,amt) {
            this.setMyRadio(true);}
```

Comment: Best practice is to use `initObservable: function() {}` rather than directly using `ko.observable` btw